# VueJs/ChartJs - single file component computed property only renders when I click the component in Vue Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, chart.js

I have a single file component that uses Chart.Js to render a simple visualization for some hard coded data. I'm calling the Chart.Js library through a CDN in the `head` section of my index.html.

I'm using the official Webpack template.

For some reason, the chart won't render unless I click on the component inside the Vue Dev Tools extension.

I've tried changing it from computed to created/mounted and that hasn't worked.

Here's my code. Any help getting this to render properly would be much appreciated.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <canvas id="carbChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      calories: 3000,
      childSex: 'male',
      childAge: 'eighteen'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    nutrientCharts: function() {
      let calories = this.calories;

      let carbCtx = document.getElementById('carbChart').getContext('2d');

      let carbChart = new Chart(carbCtx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          labels: ['Low', 'Good', 'Too Much'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'carbs',
            data: [calories * .45, calories * .65, calories * 1],
            backgroundColor: ['orange', 'blue', 'red']
          }]
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Computed properties are lazy-loaded, so they won't be computed until the template or some other part of the vue instance's code references them. You're not referencing `nutrientCharts` anywhere, so the method isn't being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the method in a `computed` property but never used it.

Assuming you want to just get this running, load the chart on mounted:

```
mounted() {
  this.nutrientCharts();
},
methods: {
  nutrientCharts: function () {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you :)